# Windows Cannot Access Specified Device

Tags: windows-10

I am using Windows 10 Pro on Desktop. All of a sudden I am overwhelmed by this error "Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file. You may not have the appropriate permissions to access the item."

The same error crops up in just about everything I try...can't go to Command Prompt, can't open Event Manager (can't run any of the Admin tools), and can't even run something like Notepad. If I click on Start and try to run any of the installed applications, there is no response at all except in case of some Windows/Microsoft apps such as Edge, Calculator, Explorer (Win+E).

I can access the task manager only if I press Ctrl + Alt + Del and select Task Manager. If I right-click on the taskbar, it shows the same error.

Somehow Microsoft Edge still works and that is how I am writing this post. I checked the Event Manager by going into Safe Mode (with Command Prompt)...there are quite a few errors...most of them with error code 1084...nothing that I can pin to this.

The same error comes up if I log into the system as another user.

The last thing I did (before this error first appeared) was add an entry into task scheduler (a file I wanted to execute when I log in)...I just removed the file (renamed it) so the task scheduler can't find it.

So, what should I do next to troubleshoot this problem?

Update:
Chkdsk and sfc /scannow didn't report any error.

Comment: Why don't you disable the scheduled task? How often was that task supposed to run?

Comment: Task was to be triggered on login. I can't disable the task from Safe Mode and I can't access the relevant MSC file in normal mode due to error. So instead I chose to rename the file.

Comment: The simplest solution might be to rollback to a system restore point from before this happened. (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: You may have a virus infection. Scan your system.

Comment: @harrymc I just did a System Restore...I had a Restore Point which was created just five days ago. Now things are back to normal. But what caused the problem in the first place is not entirely clear.

Norton didn't report any virus. That's the only AV I use but never had a problem with it except some rare false positives.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this problem is somehow related to the scheduling done of a task,
which according to you was the only manipulation done just before the
problem arrived.

Rollback to a previous System Restore Point has resolved a problem that would have
otherwise been very hard to analyze.